# What is the Swift equivalent of [UIColor colorWithWhite:alpha]

Tags: swift, uicolor

This in Objective-C returns the default iOS disabled gray color:

```
[UIColor colorWithWhite: 0.70 alpha:1];
```

There doesn't appear to be any native Swift function:

```
UIColor.colorWithWhite(0.70, alpha: 1)
```

I'm wondering if there's a different way that UIColor has implemented this in Swift that I'm not aware of? I can't seem to find anything in the docs. If not, then what would be an appropriate `extension` for this method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Swift it's all about readability and most of the static methods calls known from Objective-C are dropped now.

`[UIColor colorWithWhite:alpha]` is now `UIColor(white: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat)`

Comment: Yep, that's it! Nice. Might want to re-word your answer though, looks more like a comment ;)

Comment: Yeah I will do it as soon I am at my workplace desk :)

Answer (score 2):

UIColor(white: 0.7, alpha: 1.0)